# Document ID link not displayed in SPO

Tags: library, document-id, callouts

Document ID feature is activated and documents have assigned Document IDs, all good here.

The issue is that the only way to get a Document ID link is to open file properties and copy the Document ID link from the property.

[image: Document ID in the file properties]

Ideally, we would like to get the link in a callout window. But it doesn't show DocumentID link, it shows the direct link which can be easily broken if document renamed or moved.

[image: Callout]

Is there are any way to achieve this in SPO environment?

Regards,
Pavel

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm stuck and I find it outrageous for Microsoft to have something such as Document ID Service and being unable to actually get the link

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the "Share" option as I believe that uses the document id.  Depending on your setup you may wish to disable sharing in your permission settings which forces all share links to only work for people who have access already.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Unfortunately, share option doesn't generate the DocumentID type link.

Comment: I know this is a little old but still it's an issue.  Hopefully we can get the Copy Field to Clipboard that exists on lists applied to Document Libraries too.  This would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pavel, if you add the DocumentID column to the view you can right click it and use copy shortcut.  Not ideal but it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not, when I do right click on the DocID value the context SharePoint menu pops-up without copy shortcut option.